# Problemas en sumas Excel

Tags: excel

Resulta que tengo un archivo en el que relleno un formulario y se me van rellenando las tablas de un documento Excel por día (El día va indicado en un campo del formulario Excel). Estas tablas generan gráficos de datos. Ahora, quiero agrupar lo que genero en mis tablas por días en meses. Al sumar los datos de esos días en el mes (y hacer la pertinente comprobación de que evidentemente es ese mes) la suma me da 0. He comprobado que no es por el formato de ninguna celda y para colmo si pulso Fx en la barra de funciones, me predice como resultado el número que espero.

He estado probando también si siempre me muestra un 0 cuando sumo, o en qué casos me los muestra. Hasta ahora, parece que se me muestra un 0 cada vez que sumo celdas que tienen un valor que proviene de una fórmula, es decir, si sumo 2 valores puestos a mano los suma correctamente, pero si sumo un valor que viene de una fórmula con valores puestos a mano también me retorna un 0.

Adjunto la captura de pantalla de una de las tablas junto con la fórmula de su suma de totales a la derecha para que se entienda mejor el problema.

[image: Imagen de tabla]

Apunte:

He seguido fisgando con el problema y me acabo de dar cuenta de otro, que seguramente esté relacionado con el primero.

Resulta que yo en mi formulario tengo un campo que indica el día en el que estamos. Los datos de las tablas se van actualizando conforme al día seleccionado. La fórmula de por ejemplo la celda C4 situada en la tabla es:

=SI(Formulario!B6=Tabla1!C3;Formulario!$B2;C4)

La condición del sí solamente compara los días para saber si debe insertar en esa celda. En caso de que sea, introduce el dato, y si no, deja la celda C4 como estaba (para conservar los datos de los días anteriores).
Ahora cuando actualizo la fórmula, el valor se vuelve 0 y pierdo el dato.

Además, puedo confirmar que todo esto que está dando problemas ha estado funcionando antes.

Comment: Hola @Adrián por favor, sería bueno visualizar las cabeceras de columna y fila para poderte ayudar.

Comment: Ya actualicé la foto. He dejado también el sumatorio marcado para que se vea bien el error. Los números que aparecen marcados por el sumatorio provienen de una fórmula (un SI que coge datos de otra hoja si el día es el adecuado). Si pulso f2 para dejar de ver la fórmula el resultado es 0, cuando es obvio que no debería dar 0.

Comment: confirmame por favor, que la formula que indicas esta directamente en la celda AG4, ya que si indicas esta formula dentro de la columna AF4 lo deja a 0 (ya que se vuelve loco al sumarse a si mismo).

Comment: Sí, está en AG4. No me pasa solamente en esta tabla, me pasa en cada una de las tablas referenciadas que tengo (tengo unas 15 tablas que rellenan gráficos)

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. Dices que en la celda `C4` tienes esta formula: `=SI(Formulario!B6=Tabla1!C3;Formulario!$B2;C4)`. Estás creando una referencia circular, que produce resultados raros a veces. Deberías evitar las referencias circulares. Lee https://support.office.com/es-es/article/quitar-o-permitir-una-referencia-circular-8540bd0f-6e97-4483-bcf7-1b49cd50d123

Answer (score 0):

Justo mirando las referencias circulares he dado con el problema. El problema no eran las referencias circulares en sí, si no que el cálculo iterativo cuando existen estaba desactivado (no sé por qué).
En fin, dejo la solución por si alguien vuelve a tener esta torpeza.

Habiliitar el cálculo iterativo:

Archivo--->Opciones--->Fórmulas  y habilitar el cálculo iterativo.